# Undefined variable in actionblock template

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-cmf

This is my first SymfonyCMF application, so please bear with me, I might be fundamentally misunderstanding some concepts.

I have an ActionBlock (`/cms/content/most-recent-psa`) with an action of `FooCmsBundle:Psa:embedPsa`.

My embed function looks like this:

```
class PsaController extends Controller {

    /**
     * @Template()
     */
    public function embedPsaAction() {
        //... figure out which PSA needs to be displayed and set it to $psa

        return array('page' => $psa);
    }
}
```

I embed it in a Twig template with this: `{{ sonata_block_render({"name": "/cms/content/most-recent-psa"}) }}`

When I embed that template on a page, I get this exception: `Variable "psa" does not exist in /var/www/peacefund-cms/src/Foo/CmsBundle/Resources/views/Psa/embedPsa.html.twig at line 6`, which is just a simple output: `<h2>{{ psa.title | raw }}</h2>`.

So it looks like it's doing everything correctly.  I've made sure that $psa is a valid value when it gets returned from the `embedPsaAction` function, and it seems like it loads the template exactly as it should, but the variable isn't being exposed.

Comment: but the variable you are passing to the template is ***page*** and not *psa*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a variable named "psa", you will have to give this exact name in the controller. Here you have the "page" variable for you twig page. And the page variable for twig equals to $psa for the controller.

In your controller, you have to do that :

```
array("variableNameForTwig1" => $variableController1, "variableNameForTwig2" => $variableController2 )
```

And then in your view, you can do that :

```
{{variableNameFortwig1.attribute}}
{{variableNameFortwig2.attribute}}
```

Comment: Good lord.  I spent two hours last night fighting with this and it came down to my complete inability to read my own code.  Much thanks!

Comment: That happens frequently to me when trying out new stuff: So many unfamiliar things that the most obvious thing gets missed :-)